# How to create a variable to store AsQueryable()?

Tags: c#

I have a line of c# code like the following

```
return plists.AsQueryable().OrderBy(p => p.BillingInvoiceId).Skip(round * count).Take(count);
```

plists is a variable which is declared like this

```
List<BillingInvoiceListView> plists = new List<BillingInvoiceListView>();
```

i want to create a variable to store before returning

```
plists.AsQueryable().OrderBy(p => p.BillingInvoiceId).Skip(round * count).Take(count)
```

i've tried so many times not work, anyone knows how ?

Comment: Doesn't var myVar = ... work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to declare variable like this

```
IQueryable<BillingInvoiceListView> records = plists.AsQueryable().OrderBy(p => p.BillingInvoiceId).Skip(round * count).Take(count);
```